# Is it safe to use a Clojure core.cache guarded by ref type?

Tags: data-structures, clojure, ttl

I need a map that needs to be guarded against concurrent resources, ref type suits my case.
Now I need a "time to live" policy to remove a potential entry that my code could forget to remove.
I checked [clojure.core.cache](http://clojure.github.com/core.cache/#clojure.core.cache/TTLCache) but I'm not really sure if it is safe as the data structure to be guarded with ref type.

I prefer a pure Clojure solution but if things are going to complicated, would you suggest another approach? For example Google Guava?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "guarded against concurrent resources?"

Comment: @noahz I have a map that will be used and updated by many threads. Shared resource

Comment: Ok, and what about "I'm not really sure if it is safe as the data structure to be guarded with ref type."  What are your specific concerns?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [core.cache](http://clojure.github.com/core.cache/#clojure.core.cache/TTLCache) TTL implementation is immutable and does not change in place.  The concurrent guarantees are those of the enclosing reference type.  Of note however, is that the caches are meant for use in a certain way (protocol), described on the [core.cache wiki](https://github.com/clojure/core.cache/wiki/Using).

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is a real honor to get a reply from you.